# How to learn knockout js. Please help to learn about js,

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, magento2.3.1

**How to learn knockout js. Please help to learn about js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout(KO) is a Javascript library which helps in the frontend of Magento 2. It implements MVVM (**Model-View-View-Model**) design pattern. 
You can find Knockout JS in Magento 2 on almost every page, but mostly on the checkout page. The implementation of Magento 2 Knockout JS is a bit tricky.

reference,

1. https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html
2. https://learn.knockoutjs.com/
3. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/knockoutjs/index.htm
4. https://www.udemy.com/course/knockout-js-from-scratch/
5. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-knockoutjs/

As far as Magento KO is concern, we should know about data-bind and KO Observable is most important

Comment: Thanks @Magento Abu For helping :)